# Snap mobile viewport

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, viewport

I'm developing a site which will have a 2-3 columns depending on the page.

Mobile support is important and we're already handling orientation changes on iOS/Android/others.

The viewport is initially sized to fit the width of one column. Most mobile browsers have "sticky" horizontal scrolling  to make it easier to scroll up/down a column (minor left-right drags are ignored after significant up/down scrolling).

What I'd like is that once the users starts scrolling left/right that the scroll would "stick" again at the next column.

I don't know if this is even possible?

The alternative would be for us to size the page to the viewport with `overflow:auto;` and handle the scrolling ourselves. I imagine this would be more reliable cross-browser but it feels a little hacky and like it might be a lot of effort to polish properly.

Has anyone seen anything like this / have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually implemented something very similar to that discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849439/treating-each-div-as-a-page-when-scrolling/12849562#12849562) except with both horizontal and vertical scrolling.