# How to achieve a scrolling effect similar to the Paragon site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know what this scrolling effect is called so don't know how to search for my answer, and I can't find it in the source code. What is the code responsible for the scrolling effect at [Paragon](https://www.epicgames.com/paragon/#videoTrailers) where scrolling will cause the page to scroll down to the next div I assume. Or down a certain height.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm not sure where else to ask.

Comment: The first problem is that instead of repeating the question title which asks "how to do X" you asked for us to point out the code responsible on a third party site. The second problem is that had you asked correctly, it'd be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849439/treating-each-div-as-a-page-when-scrolling

Comment: As I mentioned, I did search for over half an hour for this but didn't know what to search to get the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've thrown together a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/grYGyb). It hase no animations but explains the general mechanics (the Paragon site does it differently but to start the following might be better suited).

The core part is this:

```
window.onwheel = function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wDelta = e.deltaY > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
    if (wDelta === "down") {
        // scroll Down
    } else {
        // scroll Up
    }
}
```

To know where to scroll we'll of course need to know where we are. There are several ways to do that. What I did is check the current `top` of the `viewport` against it's `height`.

```
var offset = window.pageYOffset,
    viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

switch (parseInt(offset/viewportHeight,0)) {
    case 0:
        // we are in the first viewport
        break;
    case 1:
        // we are in the second viewport
        break;
    ...
}
```

I just checked it for functionality. Performance wise it can be improved upon. You should also bind `keydown` (to catch `pageUp`, `pageDown`, `space` and so on) but it can be done in a similar fashion. **To ensure backwards compatibility** you'll need to expand the code (e.g. a binding to the `onmousewheel` event). But this will give you a place to start.

**PS**

Also consider what behaviour you want when reloading the page (if the user reloads while between `viewports` it will stay between them until another `scroll` occurs).

[This answer could also interest you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179)